# viewWillTransition(to:with:) with a strange size parameter on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I am facing a strange issue on iOS 13 when using `viewWillTransition(to:with:)` in a modally presented view controller (with the `modalPresentationStyle` explicitly set to `.fullScreen`).

The view hierarchy is the following:

- `UINavigationController` with `UIViewControllerA`

  - presents `UINavigationController` with `UIViewControllerB` (`modalPresentationStyle` = `.automatic`

    - presents `UIViewControllerC` (`modalPresentationStyle` = `.fullScreen`)

[image: view hierarchy]

When I rotate the device (iPhone 11 Pro) from portrait to landscape the `size` parameter (in `UIViewControllerC`) prints a strange value of `(414.0, 340.0)`. When I rotate back to portrait it (correctly) prints `(375.0, 812.0)` (the full screen size).

On a simulator using an iOS version < 13 the `size` parameter correctly prints `(375.0, 812.0)` for portrait / `(812.0, 375.0)` for landscape orientation.

When I use a `modalPresentationStyle` of `.fullScreen` for **both** presentations everything works as expected (even on iOS 13).

I assume this has to do with the new sheet presentation behaviour. But I am not sure if this wrong size is a bug or I just do not get the new logic yet.

Hope to find some guidance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to find a reason of this behaviour?

Comment: I am just now dealing with the exact same issue but I get 414x692 when going back fro landscape to portrait. I am using an ordinary view controller.